# Is there a way to hide a QGraphicsProxyWidget but keep the widget set to it visible?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I have a QGraphicsProxyWidget, proxy, and a custom QPushButton, button. I am using the proxy.setWidget(button).

The relevant code:

```
class CtrlSelectorButton(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, ctrl_picker_view):
        super(CtrlSelectorButton, self).__init__()
        self.ctrl_picker_view = ctrl_picker_view

        self.proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self.ctrl_picker_view.buttons_group)
        self.proxy.setWidget(self)
```

I need to be able to customize the button so that it has rounded corners, and can be smaller than the button's label, which is causing the proxy to extend beyond the button's appearance in these cases. Is there a way to hide the appearance of the proxy without hiding the button? Everything I have tried for hiding on the proxy affects the button.

For extra context, I have a UI with an image, and buttons placed on top of that image. I have a zoom function, and the only way I have been able to get drag selecting over the buttons to work when zoomed in or out is by putting the button in a proxy. Without the proxy, the drag selecting does not respect the button's zoomed in/out position.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're doing nor why: what do you mean by "customize the button so that it has rounded corners, and can be smaller than the button's label"? And "extend beyond the button's appearance in these cases"? I'm under the impression that you're doing too many things for the wrong reasons. Please clarify the purpose of the button (and why you actually need a QPushButton) and the issue about zooming, as right now it's very obscure.

Comment: Post a [mre]. You mean removing pixels outside the border? You can try ```self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)```.